# Does Google bot crawl dynamically created iframes?

Tags: seo, javascript, googlebot, iframe

The situation looks as followed:

1. User includes Javascript snippet into his page.
2. Javascript creates iFrame dynamically and appends it to page.
3. iFrame has static content.

**Is Google bot smart enough to crawl iFrame's static content?**

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34445?hl=en

Comment: Do you want Google to crawl/index this content? Or are you trying to hide it from search engines?

Comment: @w3d: I want to index it.

Answer (score 1):

Google isn't able to crawl iframe content under two circumstances:

- the iframe source path isn't present as a clear path in any document, which can be crawled by Google
- the javascript, which inserts iframe, starts acting on user action, like onClick.

If iframe source path is present anywhere in the source code, Googlebot will read it, recognize `Aha! Looks like... a path to anything! Lets go and try to read it!` So to make the iframe path unreadable for the Googlebot, it should be obfuscated by javascript.

Also, to achieve the goal, that Google isn't able to crawl the iframe content, the javascript should

- obfuscate the iframe source path
- on user action de-obfuscate and load it

In any other case Googlebot will crawl iframe content.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I read that the Google bot is more powerful than you described: http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157. Now I am confused.

Comment: "to achieve the goal" - it seems the OP wants to index the content, not hide it. The OP makes no mention of a "user action". I would assume that this is created on page load.